# How to get previously assign image and title from uibutton with respect to tag value?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have an UIView in which

my .h header file

```
UIButton *btn;
```

and in my .m implementation file

```
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5,5,circleImage.frame.size.width-10,circleImage.frame.size.height-10);
            [btn setFrame: frame];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[GrideImgArray objectAtIndex:count]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        btn.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [btn setTag:btnTagValue];
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [circleImage addSubview:btn];
```

in my button clicked method

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
     //do something
}
```

now my problem is i have one more uibutton and tha method are moreOptionClicked

```
-(void)MoreOptionOnClick:(UIButton *)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:sender.tag];//same tag as (btn.tag=sender.tag)
NSLog(@"%@",button.titleLabel.text);
NSLog(@"%@",button.imageView.image);
}
```

in this method i want previously assign button whic is (btn) title and image also but in moreOptionClick this two NSLog methods return null

**IMP :- btn tag is equal to sender.tag show i have same tag for both uibutton**

Any answers will be appreciated

Comment: Hi, i noticed two problems in your code, one is you are assigning same value to tag property for both the buttons, then which one will viewWithTag method return is not predictable, and another is if you are already getting button in sender, then why are you trying to create its reference using viewWithTag ?

Comment: @harishmistry both method are diffrent my first method is buttonClicked:sender which is for first UIButton and my secound method is MoreOptionClicked:sender which is my secound UIButton method.

Comment: Okay @Visnu then which button object you are trying to get in MoreOptionOnClick: method ?

Comment: @harishmistry btn which is my first button name.

Comment: @Vishu: Have you gone through my explanation given in the comment of my answer?

Comment: @Visnu i have one alternate solution for it as you mentioned that you already declared your button in .h header file then i guess you can access it easily in .m file also then why you are creating its reference using viewWithTag: i'm confused can you elaborate the scenario a bit more clear ?

Comment: @Visnu did it worked to use the object you declared it in .h file ?

Comment: @harishmistry i want title and image of first button when i pressed secound button.thats why i give same tag for this bcz i have more than 300 uibutton so i want both tag same when user click on secound button i get exact tag value which is same as first uibutton and than get image and title of first button.

Comment: @Visnu giving same tag value to two different button is the problem because viewWithTag: method may return any button reference at that time.

I suggest to maintain an array of buttons and access them using the array indexes like OutletCollections.

Comment: @harishmistry when i give diffrent tag then also i don't get title and image value it gives null ?? what should i do ??

Comment: @Visnu please check the code i just wrote in the answer.

Comment: recheck my code i have following line : -[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[GrideImgArray objectAtIndex:count]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get UIButton by using this `[self.view viewWithTag:1];` .
But you are having two views with same tag.
You may set same tag with different sign to the two different UIButtons.
Say tag 100 to btn1 and -100 to btn2.
and in your method you may get another button based on sign of the button tag.

```
[fristbtn setTag:100];
[secondbtn setTag:-100];
```

and in your method.

```
-(IBAction)MoreOptionOnClick:(UIButton *)sender{
//suppose sender is secondbtn.
int iSuperTag=0-sender.tag;//you will get 100.
 UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:iSuperTag];
 NSLog(@"%@",button.titleLabel.text);
 NSLog(@"%@",button.imageView.image);
}
```

Comment: but i want same tag for both uibuttons. if both tag are not same how i get previous uibutton title and image values ??

Comment: See I am saying you set same tag with the difference of + and - sign. Same value with different sign. So that when you get 100 you may get "viewwithtag" of -100 and vice versa. I hope this clears my solution.

Comment: but it again give (null) when i print button.titleLAble.text and image also ??

Comment: [fistbtn setTag:100]; [secoundbtn setTag:-100]; and then in my secound btn method i do someting like thatUIButton             *button = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:-sender.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",button.titleLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"%@",button.imageView.image);

Comment: it gives [619:207] (null)

Comment: I will get same tag but i want it's title and image also but it give null values

Comment: @Vishu: Yes I did its giving me properly <UIImage: 0xb83dcc0> object.Please note: button.imageview.image gives you foreground image and not background image

Comment: Try using "[button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal]" if you are setting background image view to the button. Works perfectly at my end

Comment: so how i get background image and why i get title null ?? plz expalin

Comment: but title is still returns null value ??

Comment: Pooja M. Bohora Can i ask one more doubt please ??

Answer (score 0):

@Visnu i tried the same as below, and it works fine the only difference i see in your code and mine is that you didn't set any title or image for button, an i did.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIButton *btnA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnA setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [btnA setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect frameA = CGRectMake(5,5,100,30);
    [btnA setFrame: frameA];
    [btnA setTag:1];
    [btnA addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnA];

    UIButton *btnB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnB setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    CGRect frameB = CGRectMake(50,50,100,30);
    [btnB setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnB setFrame: frameB];
    [btnB setTag:2];
    [btnB addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMoreOptionOnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnB];
}


- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{

}

-(IBAction)btnMoreOptionOnClick:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    NSLog(@"%@", button.titleLabel.text);
}
```

Try this code it works fine....